# How to write in a two-dimensional array of another class the size of only one-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I create a two-dimensional array and initialize only one dimension of the array, everything works, but if I call it from another class, nothing works. why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coursework   {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int verticalMatrix; // vertical size of Matrix
    int horisontMatrix; // horisont


    System.out.println("Enter vertical size of Matrix ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    verticalMatrix = sc.nextInt();

    int [][] matrix = new int [verticalMatrix][];

}}
```

This code works, but when I use extends class Matrix I can't save only one size (verticalMatrix). How fix it?

```
public class Coursework extends Matrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int verticalMatrix; // vertical size of Matrix
    int horisontMatrix; // horisont


    System.out.println("Enter vertical size of Matrix ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    verticalMatrix = sc.nextInt();

    int [][] matrix = new int [verticalMatrix][];
```

Matrix Class

```
    public class Matrix {

    public static int [][] Matrix;

    public void getSize(){  
            System.out.println("This method still epmty");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because "nothing works" is not a useful problem statement.  Please [edit] your question to clarify your problem, and this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: change the name of variable public static int [][] Matrix to something else besides the name of the class containing it

Comment: "..I can't save only one size.." Why not? Do you get an error? What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your int array variable called just like your class (`Matrix`). This does probably not cause an error but it is not preferred. You can pass the vertical length of the array t the constructor, like this:

```
public class Matrix {

    public static int [][] matrix;

    public void Matrix(int verticalLength){
        this.matrix = new int[verticalLength][];
    }

    public void getSize(){  
            System.out.println("This method still epmty");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but how to use method Matrix(int verticallength) in main class? how to call this method and  initial data?

Comment: You get the data from the user in your Main method (or you could write a helper class) and then you create an object using the constructor of the Matrix class. If you don’t know how tu use a constructor, go look it up.